# Can a Raspberry Pi send a binary 1/0 to a VAV controller and which board is best for this?

Tags: python, output

My senior project is to take in webcam footage, determine the number of people in the room, and if there is more than 0 people in the room send an "on" signal to a VAV controller. I'm handling the person recognition with python code. If there is more than 0 people in the room, python will print true or false. Can I send this true or false value to some pin on a Raspberry Pi such that it will output a binary signal 1 or 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I send this true or false value to some pin on a Raspberry Pi such that it will output a binary signal 1 or 0?

Yes.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=toggle+gpio+%5Bpython%5D